# Quartic analog of the quadratic series of Au-Yeung

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series

The identity
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left (\frac{H_n}{n}\right)^2=\frac{17}{4}\zeta(4)=\frac{17\pi^4}{360},$$
where $H_n=1+1/2+1/3+\ldots 1/m$ is the  harmonic number, was discovered numerically by Enrico Au–Yeung and  proved rigorously by David Borwein and Jonathan Borwein (see https://rd.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00283-021-10106-5).

What is known about its quartic counterpart (that is about the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left (H_n/n\right)^4$)?

Note that the cubic counterpart was considered in http://jca.ele-math.com/09-15/Evaluation-of-a-cubic-Euler-sum

Answer (score 2):

All sums of the form $\sum_{n\ge1}H_n^i/n^j$ are expressible as rational linear combination of multiple zeta values (MZV) of weight $i+j$. In weight
$4$ as in your first example, the dimension of the space of MZV is one, so necessarily the sum is a rational multiple of $\zeta(4)$. For $i=j=4$ the weight is $8$ and the dimension is $4$, and your sum can be expressed as a rational linear combination of any Q-basis, for instance on the Hoffmann basis it has coefficients $(1167412/4125, -14372/275, -14788/275, -13452/275)$,
but these numbers have no intrinsic meaning since the Hoffmann basis is one among many possible bases. However, it proves (conjecturally) that the sum is not a rational multiple of $\zeta(8)$.

Comment: I found in https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X17303372 a statement that all the 29 Euler sums of weight 8 are reducible to a linear sum $S_{2,6}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^6}\approx 1.0218970966$ and zeta values. In particular, $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H^4_n}{n^4}=\frac{13559}{144}\,\zeta(8)-92\zeta(3)\zeta(5)-2\zeta(2)\zeta(3)^2+26S_{2,6}.$$ It looks like this relation was first obtained in https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X17300835

Comment: Sure, and your $S_{2,6}$ is an MZV. Your chosen basis is simpler.